# On iAd Network iPhone App status is configured and live but not serving ad on device

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

iPhone News Application is now Ready for sale and on iAd Network status is 
 - Live: This app is receiving live ads. You have configured ad
   preferences for this app.
After Purchased not showing any kind of ad please help.

Comment: What did you do inside your app code? Did you make use of `ADBannerView`?

Comment: Did you see test ads during development? (black banners with white text)

Comment: Test Banner is working fine during development on simulator and device  but not after when i download the app from app store.

Comment: Sorry  I know that i shouldnt comment, but I have the same issue  (my app is already on the appstore  iad-live ) but no banners or interstitials ads , Please share  how much time did it take to get  your ads  showing properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be surprising not to see live ads when the app is on the App Store.

But it's *not*: **iAd fill rate is usually low**.
You don't get an ad each time you request one, but only if iAd is delivering ad campaigns at the moment.

I've been experiencing this. No ads for a long time, and then they started popping for a major campaign.

As a comparison, you have a very high fill rate with AdMob but a low revenue (eCPM). It's quite the opposite for iAd: low fill rate, high eCPM.

I think you can increase iAd fill rate by enabling developer ads (ads for other apps), but it will decrease the revenue revenue for the other campaigns.